# How to connect a voltage and current source?

Tags: circuit-design, current-source, voltage-source

I'm currently trying to figure out a circuit design to connect a voltage source with a current source. More specifically, I have a power supply that has a safety current loop that is wired to an E-STOP button. I have a second supply used for a different part of my build, but that one has a voltage 5V safety loop. Is there anyway I could have both safety loops as part of one loop for the e-stop?

The thought process between connecting them is that the voltage safety loop currently has limit switches that need to also shut down the supply with the current safety loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s safe to assume that you can’t just join the two together.  If you want to disable both power supplies in an e-stop situation then you could use a 2-pole relay to interrupt both circuits.  Typically you’ll use normally-open contacts so that e-stop occurs if the relay is de-energised for any reason.  E-stop switches are then connected in series and should all be normally closed to keep the relay energised in. Or mal operation.

Comment: That makes sense. So just to confirm, the existing limit switches would be used to open and close the 2-pole relay which would close the 2 separate power supply loops, where each of those loops is wired to the e-stop on separate contractor blocks, so that either limit switches or estop will shut everything off

Comment: Yes Exactly that